# Obtain leaflet layergroup by name string

Tags: leaflet

Follow the example on leaflet map (http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control.html), I can create a layer group `cities`, which showed in `overlayMaps` `Cities`.

In the later stage (i.e. another function), is it possible to get the object `layer group` by name `cities` or `Cities`? Then I can use it in another function (e.g. leaflet-search (https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search)).

This is my pseudo code to demo my question

```
 find_layer_by_name = function(name){
     // add code here
 };
 var searchLayer = find_layer_by_name('cities');
 var searchcontrol = new L.Control.Search({layer: searchLayer});
```

Let me know if my question is not clear.

Comment: do you want to get `cities` from here `var overlayMaps = {
    "Cities": cities
};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have created an `overlayMaps` object with key/value pairs (as in the Leaflet example), you can use square bracket notation with your key as a string to get the corresponding layer. The following will assign `cities` to `searchLayer`:

```js
var overlayMaps = {
  "Cities": cities
};

var searchLayer = overlayMaps["Cities"];
```